# Magical Camera Error in onActivityResult and Path or Bitmap is null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, camera

I am using [Magical Camera](https://github.com/fabian7593/MagicalCamera) library to take photos. Works perfect on Android 7 but starting Android 8.0 crashing when I took photo (when calls `magicalCamera.resultPhoto(requestCode, resultCode, data);` on onActivityResult) its crashing. Shows error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference`. Called take photo method by clicking button:

```
takePhotoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isActivePermission(MagicalCamera.CAMERA)) {
                magicalCamera.takePhoto();
            }
        }
    });
```

Trying to get photo:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    magicalCamera.resultPhoto(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

How I can solve this problem. Checked all permissions (Wrote permissions into Manifest file).

Comment: Seems like its a problem with the library, since there is more than one open case from the library source

https://github.com/fabian7593/MagicalCamera/issues/40 https://github.com/fabian7593/MagicalCamera/issues/43 https://github.com/fabian7593/MagicalCamera/issues/21